# Подсчет одинаковых слов, от наибольшего количества к наименьшему. PHP

Tags: php

Добрый день!
 Имеется набор слов. К примеру: "Лондон Париж Лондон Москва Париж Лондон Киев Париж Лондон Киев".
 Необходимо получить результат в порядке уменьшения:
Лондон - 4
Париж - 3
Киев - 2
Москва - 1

С задачей смогла справиться частично (и то не совсем))):

```
 $str = 'Лондон Париж Лондон Москва Париж Лондон Киев Париж Лондон Киев';
 echo substr_count($str, 'Лондон').'<br>';
```

Подскажите, как реализовать, если неизвестно какие будут слова и чтобы результат был в порядке уменьшения?

Comment: Вы задали к текущему моменту уже 10 вопросов на сайте. На большинство ваших вопросов дано по несколько ответов. Ни один ответ не отмечен как решение вопроса. Вам действительно не подошёл ни один ответ или вы принципиально не отмечаете подошедшие ответы как решение ваших вопросов?

Comment: я выбирала необходимые ответы как правильные, но мне уточнялось, что необходима репутация от 15. Я ее еще не набрала ((

Comment: вам возможно репутация нужна чтобы upvote сделать ответу, а чтобы отметить его как Правильный, репутации не требуется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сохраняем с кодировкой UTF-8 без BOM. Именно такой кодировки должен быть текст.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$str = 'Лондон Париж Лондон Москва Париж Лондон Киев Париж Лондон Киев';
// разбиваем на слова, модификатор u используется для юникод строки
$words = preg_split("/([^[:alnum:]]|['-])+/us", $str);

// оставляем только уникальные слова
$words = array_unique($words);
$arr = array();
// считаем какие из слов сколько встречаются раз
foreach($words as $word)
{
    $arr[$word] = substr_count($str, $word);
}
// сортируем, оставляя ключи массива
arsort($arr);
// выводим
foreach ($arr as $city => $count)
{
    echo $city.' - '.$count.'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$in = 'Лондон Париж Лондон Москва Париж Лондон Киев Париж Лондон Киев';

$words = explode(' ', $in);
$out = [];
foreach($words as $word){
    isset($out[$word])?$out[$word]++:$out[$word]=1;
}

arsort($out);

print_r($out);
```

[sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/89be1364bde9cfc758d3227926fff557a992db08)

Answer (score 2):

explode поделит строку на токены, создав массив. array_count_values сгруппирует массив и посчитает количества. Ну и array_multisort расположит элементы в нужном порядке.